# Change value of an XML attribute via xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML file:

```
</disk>
<disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
  <source file='discovery.iso' index='1'/>
  <backingStore/>
  <target dev='hdd' bus='ide'/>
  <readonly/>
  <alias name='ide0-1-1'/>
  <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='1' target='0' unit='1'/>
</disk>
```

and want to change a bus='ide' to bus='scsi'

my template looks like, but when I run it...

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="disk[@type='file']/target">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="bus">scsi</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I got an error then I run my Terraform:

```
 xdr:DecodeUint: EOF while decoding 4 bytes - read
```

What I did miss?

Comment: Please don't say that something "doesn't work". Always tell us how it fails. Diagnosis starts with the symptoms.

Comment: And show more appropriate source and xslt.

Comment: I got an 
 xdr:DecodeUint: EOF while decoding 4 bytes - read

Answer (score 1):

Your stylesheet lacks a template that copies all nodes that are *not* matched by your given template:

```xml
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```